# In GAS trigger event code, how to find out which Google calendar event was updated?

Tags: events, google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

Using the advanced Calendar API Service (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) in Google Apps Script, I have found that you can cause an event handler function to be called when the calendar is updated (see screenshot), and that works fine: each time an event is added or changed it appears that my function is called.  However I can't figure out which Calendar Event (i.e. appointment) has been modified.  The handler function is called with 1 arg (e) which is of type "event", but it doesn't seem to contain the ID or any reference to the calendar event that was updated.  Here is my handler code:

```
function triggeredOnUpdate(e){
  Logger.log('Update event: %s', e);

  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var eventId = e.<????what goes here???>;
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);

  Logger.log('Running update on Calendar Event: %s', event.summary);
  colourEvent(calendarId, event);
}
```

And the log output is:

> Update event: {authMode=FULL, calendarId=mycalendar@mydomain.com, triggerUid=1325034127}

That TriggerUID is the ID of the trigger, so its the same every time this handler is called.

Do you know how I can find out which Calendar Event has been updated?

(Note: the word event is overloaded when talking about triggers in a calendar: there's a calendar event, like an appointment, and the update event, when that appointment is changed)

[image: 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDr4A.png)

Comment: Hello, mind sharing how you created that trigger handler for the calendar event?

Comment: Sure - the  handler is just a function in my AppScript project, I called it triggeredOnUpdate.  Then in the project browser, under Resources, I selected Current Project's Triggers and selected that function, with From Calendar and Entry Updated - you can see that in the screen shot above.

Comment: It's so strange I've never seen this option before and I don't have the option, is your script binded to something? did you add installable triggers? maybe some specific scope?

Comment: Have you enabled the Advanced Calendar API?  You may need that.  Or it could be that i am in an early access programme? Anyway, it's just a use interface for installable triggers - so i guess you can do the same in code.

Comment: are you in the early access of apps scripts/appmaker? I am there, since TT but  I've never seen the trigger before! yeah I tried the alendars API and all that! we might be in diffferent early access programmes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this workflow to get the event ID:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#eventupdated

In summary: use `Calendar.Events.list` with the calendar address you got in the function parameter to perform a full sync, which includes `nextSyncToken` which can be saved in script properties.

The next time the event is triggered, you can perform an incremental sync by supplying `nextSyncToken` to `Calendar.Events.list`. This will give you the events since the last sync.

See also:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
function calendarUpdate(e) {
  var calendarId = e.calendarId;
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  //Logger.log("Event Raised: " + calendarId);
  var properties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var options = {};

  var syncToken = properties.getProperty('syncToken'); // pointer token from last sync also stored in user properties
  if (syncToken) {                        // if there is a sync token from last time
    options.syncToken = syncToken; // adds the current sync token to the list of sync options
  } else {
    // Sync events from today onwards.
    options.timeMin = new Date().toISOString(); //change to new Date().toISOString() from getRelativeDate(-1, 0).toISOString()
    
  }    
  var eventResponse;
  var pageToken = null;
  try{
    
    do{      
      var eventResponse = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, options);
      pageToken = eventResponse.nextPageToken;
      //Logger.log ('PageToken: %s', pageToken);

      if(eventResponse.nextSyncToken != null){
        options.syncToken = eventResponse.nextSyncToken;
        properties.setProperty('syncToken', eventResponse.nextSyncToken)
        //Logger.log ('NextSyncToken: %s', eventResponse.nextSyncToken);
      }      

      var events = eventResponse.items;
      for (var j=0; j<events.length; j++) {
        var e = calendar.getEventById(events[j].id);        
        var title = e.getTitle();
        var description = e.getDescription();

        //Logger.log ('Event Title: %s', title);

        if (title.includes("Basketball")) {
          e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.YELLOW);
        }
        if (description.includes("Tennis")) {
          e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.MAUVE);
        } 
      }
      options.nextPageToken = pageToken;

    }while(pageToken != null);
  } catch (ex){
    Logger.log ('Exception: %s', ex);
  }
}
```