# Google scripts calendar "Event Updated" trigger: How to find the details (title id etc) of the triggering event?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-calendar-api

I have created a function that runs with the "Event Updated" trigger. The function simply Logger.log's some text so I know it works. It looks like:

```
function deleteCalendarEvent(e){
 
  Logger.log('an event was deleted or updated');

}
```

Now I would like to find which calendar event caused the trigger so I can do some work with it. This is where I am stuck and found this similar question from 2 years back with no answer:

[In GAS trigger event code, how to find out which Google calendar event was updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398884/in-gas-trigger-event-code-how-to-find-out-which-google-calendar-event-was-updat)

It would be good to get a pointer or be told it's impossible if that's the case (although I don't really get why you'd have the trigger at all if it was so limited).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events